# Image Lazy loading images "jumping"

Tags: javascript, html, image, css, lazy-loading

Hey i wanna lazy load the images on my page, so i created a data-src tag on my images tags and then i load it.

I know there ar many libs etc. but i have to learn js and css so i tired to to it whitout any help.

Now the problem is, the images hav no initial height so when the load the whole page is "jumping around"

here my js code:

```
var smuLazyLoad = (function (self) {
var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];

var defaultSetup = {
    classSelector: "lazy",
    loadDelay: 100,
    fadeTime: 0.5
};

self.setup = {};

self.init = function (options) {
    options = options || {};
    self.setup.loadDelay = options.loadDelay || defaultSetup.loadDelay;
    self.setup.classSelector = options.classSelector || defaultSetup.classSelector;
    self.setup.fadeTime = options.fadeTime || defaultSetup.fadeTime;
    self.appendHelperStyles();
    self.addEvent('load',window,self.selectImages)
};


self.selectImages = function () {
    var tags = document.getElementsByClassName(self.setup.classSelector);
    for (var i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
        self.loadImage(tags[i]);
    }
    self.appendShowCss();
};

self.appendShowCss = function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        var style = document.createElement('style');
        style.innerText = "." + self.setup.classSelector + "{opacity:1 !important;}";
        body.appendChild(style);
    }, self.setup.loadDelay);
};

self.loadImage = function (tag) {
    var imageUrl = tag.getAttribute('data-src');
    tag.setAttribute('src', imageUrl);
};


self.appendHelperStyles = function () {
    var style = document.createElement('style');
    style.innerText = "." + self.setup.classSelector + "{transition:all ease-in " + self.setup.fadeTime + "s;}";
    body.appendChild(style);
};


self.addEvent = function (ev,ele,func) {
    if (ele.addEventListener)
        ele.addEventListener(ev,func,false);
    else if (elem.attachEvent) {
        ele.attachEvent("on"+ev, func);
    }
    else {
        ele[ev] = func;
    }
};
return self;
 }(smuLazyLoad || {}));
```

and my image tags ... (twig/craftcms)

```
    <img src="/onePxImage.jpg"
         alt="{{ image.title }}"
         data-src="/{{ image.getUrl('teaserImage') }}"
         style="opacity: 0;"
         class="lazy"
         width="{{ image.getHeight('teaserImage') }}"
         height="{{ image.getWidth('teaserImage') }}"
    >
```

Comment: what do you think about my js code ? ... i tried to use the module patten, is this a good idea for such a case?

Comment: If you don't know the image size beforehand DOM is ready you're pretty much at the mercy of seeing your "lazy-placeholders" *jump* while your lazy load starts requesting the image from the server. The code seems ok-ish, but I don't understand exactly the way you're doing that lazyloading and why you append styles dynamically. Seems strange.

Comment: The principle of storing the image `src` inside a `data-src` attr is OK, but I'd make it completely different: I'd load the images only when necessary, and that means: 1. set the `src` to a loading gif 2.when a `data-src` element is inside or near the viewport I'd than init the server request for that image. - That way the user will not load images that will never see anyways.